# echo two arrays from csv

Tags: php, csv

I have 2 array from data.csv
How can I use while loop to print out both array
I can only print out 1st array and it keep loop same array.

```
        $file = fopen("data.csv","r");

        while(!feof($file)){
          print_r(fgetcsv($file));
          }

        fclose($file);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $file=fgetcsv($file);
    $num=0;

    while($num<4){
        echo $file[0] . $file[1] . $file[2] . $file[3] . "<br/>";
        $num++;
        }

         ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
            Array
            (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
            )
            Array
            (
            [0] => e
            [1] => f
            [2] => g
            [3] => h
            )
```

Comment: After echoing you have to run fgetcsv() again. Or, put it as the first statement inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to do your task

```
$source = fopen('zipcode.csv', 'r') or die("Problem open file");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($source, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $col1 = $data[0];
        $col2 = $data[1];
        $col3 = $data[2];


        echo $col1 . ' ' . $col2 . ' ' . $col3 . '<br />';

    }
    fclose($source);
```

Comment: This one work!, can you explain how this works?
why put ($data=fgetcsv($source, 1000, ",") inside of condition
why !==FALSE?

Comment: `$source` = file handel, `1000` = the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file, `,` = delimiter  and `!== FALSE` use from prevent to warning of `assignment in condition`

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop will output the same thing 4 times.  I think you want to do something like"

```
while($num<4)
{ echo $file[$num]."<br>";
$num++;
}
```